# How to make Emacs modline in color?

Tags: emacs, colors

I've seen number of times emacs screenshots where modline is in color like this one:

[image]

How can I do this in emacs?

Comment: This blog is what launched my mode-line customization -- it's a very good starting point (in my opinion):  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html  You can also look at advanced libraries such as Emacs Powerline and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try packages like [powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline), [smart-mode-line](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line) which do lot of customization to mode line and has some inbuilt themes.

You can get various themes from [airline-themes](https://github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/airline-themes)

Here is a screenshot of powerline theme

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See the Elisp manual, node [Properties in Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Properties-in-Mode.html).

Mode-line constructs can be complex - or simple. At their simplest they are strings. And you can propertize strings, i.e., give them text properties, including properties such as `face` that provide visual effects such as foreground and background color.